# How to callculate max number allocations for std::multiset containing maximum N elements?

Tags: c++, hashmap, std, red-black-tree, multiset

I pushed 6 objects to std::multimap but I see 8 outputs from allocator in console. Why? Is it always N+2? How to calculate max number of allocations for N elements?

I want to use static array inside allocator and return pointers to it elements for data locality.

```
template <class T>
struct Mallocator {
  typedef T value_type;
  Mallocator() = default;
  template <class U> constexpr Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) noexcept {}
  T* allocate(std::size_t n) {
    if (n > std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(T)) throw std::bad_alloc();
    if (auto p = static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(n * sizeof(T)))) { std::cout << "allocate" << std::endl; return p; }
    throw std::bad_alloc();
  }
  void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t) noexcept { std::cout << "free" << std::endl;  std::free(p); }
};
template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const Mallocator<T>&, const Mallocator<U>&) { return true; }
template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const Mallocator<T>&, const Mallocator<U>&) { return false; }

int main()
{
  std::multiset<int, std::less<int>, Mallocator<int>> hashMap;

  hashMap.insert(1);
  hashMap.insert(2);
  hashMap.insert(3);
  hashMap.insert(4);
  hashMap.insert(5);
  hashMap.insert(6);

  _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it was specified how the implementation goes for the multiset, set, etc. The number you are looking for might be different numbers for different platforms / versions of STL / or increase unexpectedly with the total number of allocations.

I advise you to use the polymorphic allocator (introduced in C++17) instead of making your own or simply implement a simple multiset that supports up to the desired number of elements.

Comment: I just want to keep data local for speed without polymorphism and virtual calls

Comment: That's a very vague answer, but a legitimate answer nevertheless.

Comment: @Robotex then simply make an implementation of the multiset (with the required features) for a given size. Why I don't recommend to use `std::multiset` for stack-allocated data is because converting data from one allocator to another is complicated and overly template heavy (since you'll need allocator type per max-size of `multiset`). In general, only in rare cases any of this is necessary or preferred. You'd better consider redesigning your program to work with vectors instead of multisets. There might be much simplier and efficient algorithm that meet requirements for what you truly need.

Comment: I need something as fast as priority_queue but with random access for D* lite implementation

Comment: @Robotex wait... `std::multiset` does not exactly provide random access. You can only iterate over it or check for element count. Also, `priority_queue` is not necessarily faster than `set`.

Comment: priority queue can't delete and update element.

I wrote my own: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231266/my-implementation-of-binary-heap